# Puppeteer: How to Select radio button list when there is no id

Tags: javascript, automation, radio-button, click, puppeteer

I want to be able to select the radio button based on the value.

Tried something like `await page.click('button[value="critical_skill_inbound"]');`

This is what the HTML looks like.

```html
<input 
  aria-checked="true" 
  ng-value="c.value" 
  ng-model="fieldValue" 
  ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" 
  ng-disabled="field.isReadonly()" 
  ng-init="onButtonLoad()"
  name="radio_button_down_79a9d2dadbbb105022df84a2149619ef_65a9d2dadbbb105022df84a2149619da"
  type="radio" 
  class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" 
  role="radio" 
  value="critical_skill_inbound" 
  aria-invalid="false" 
  tabindex="0" 
  style=""
>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what ended up fixing it for me. I had to inspect the element and copied the selector for the radio button which was `#sp_formfield_inbound_enquiry_type > div > div:nth-child(8) > label > input`

I implemeted it here:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
       var test = document.querySelector('#sp_formfield_inbound_enquiry_type > div > div:nth-child(8) > label > input[type="radio"]')
        test.click();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an input field, but you have `button` in the selector. Try this:

```js
await page.click('input[value="critical_skill_inbound"]');
```